# How to test a form on Play Framework 2.5?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I' m new to `PlayFramework`, so I' m reading about it [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaGuide4). However, the link is for an older version, `2.1.1`:

```
@Test
public void authenticateSuccess() {
    Result result = callAction(
        controllers.routes.ref.Application.authenticate(),
        fakeRequest().withFormUrlEncodedBody(ImmutableMap.of(
            "email", "bob@example.com",
            "password", "secret"))
    );
    assertEquals(302, status(result));
    assertEquals("bob@example.com", session(result).get("email"));
}
```

How the code above would look like in the current version `2.5` ?

Answer (score 4):

For those who might be in the same situation, here's how I solved my problem:

```
@Test
public void authenticateAndRedirect() {
    Result result = route(new Http.RequestBuilder()
            .method(POST)
            .bodyForm(ImmutableMap.of("email", "valter@example.com", "password", "secret"))
            .uri(controllers.routes.ApplicationController.authenticate().url()));
    assertEquals(SEE_OTHER, result.status());
}

@Test
public void authenticateAndRedirectJson() throws Exception {

    JsonNode jsonNode = (new ObjectMapper()).readTree("{ \"email\": \"valter@example.com\", \"password\": \"secret\"  }");
    Http.RequestBuilder request = new Http.RequestBuilder()
            .method("POST")
            .bodyJson(jsonNode)
            .uri(controllers.routes.ApplicationController.authenticate().url());
    Result result = route(request);

    assertEquals(SEE_OTHER, result.status());
}
```

Keep in mind that I' m redirecting the user to another page once he' s authenticated, that' s why I' m expecting the code `SEE_OTHER=303`

```
public Result authenticate() {
    Form<Login> form = formFactory.form(Login.class).bindFromRequest();

    if (form.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(login.render(form));
    }

    Optional<User> maybeUser = User.findByEmail(form.get().email);

    if (maybeUser.isPresent()) {
        session("email", maybeUser.get().email);
        return redirect(routes.ApplicationController.index());
    }

    return badRequest(login.render(form));
}
```